# GLib-GObject Error: Mutex Assertion, Aborted Core Dump

Tags: ros-melodic, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run this tutorial (melodic remote PC, kinetic turtlebot 2)

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw
```

I confirmed via `rostopic list` and `rostopic echo` that there is data being published this this topic from the turtlebot.

The result I got on remote PC was:

```
[ INFO] [1559771301.130415330]: Using transport "raw"

(image_raw:20170): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:48:21.136: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What did I do wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324758/glib-gobject-critical-**:-16:48:21.136:-g_object_unref:-assertion-%27g_is_object-(object)%27-failed-attempt-to-unlock-mutex-that-was-not-locked-aborted-(core-dumped)/) by [lukewd](https://answers.ros.org/users/37399/lukewd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2019-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I had installed via `apt-get install ros-melodic-image-view`, somehow removing that and cloning the git repository into my `src` folder and performing a `catkin_make` fixed the problem

https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline

---

Originally posted by [lukewd](https://answers.ros.org/users/37399/lukewd/) with karma: 116 on 2019-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on 2019-06-08**:
This is related to this [solution](http://answers.ros.org/question/273258/unable-to-view-image-using-image_view-in-ros-indigo-with-rosberrypi_cam/), I think the image_view package has to be revised.